# How to create an Action Creator that makes 2 API calls with axios and returns 1 payload?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating a weather app, which detects your location coordinates using freegeoip's API, and then takes those coordinates to connect to the openweather API, which returns a data set with your current location's weather.

Action Creator code:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_CITIES = 'FETCH_CITIES';
export const FETCH_CURRENT_CITY = 'FETCH_CURRENT_CITY';

const API_KEY = '95108d63b7f0cf597d80c6d17c8010e0';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export function fetchCurrentCity() {
  const request = axios.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
    .then(response => {
      const lat = reponse.data.latitude;
      const lon = response.data.longitude;
      const url = `${ROOT_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;

      axios.get(url);
    }) 

  console.log('Request 2:', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_CURRENT_CITY,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Reducer code:

```
import { FETCH_CURRENT_CITY } from '../actions/index';

const INITIAL_STATE = { location: {}, temp: null, weather: null };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_CURRENT_CITY:
    console.log('Received2:', action.payload.data);
    return { ... state, temp: action.payload.data.main.temp, weather: action.payload.data.weather[0].main };
  }
  return state;
}
```

Console logs:

```
Request 2: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

Received2: undefined
```

Above code doesn't seem to work. I'm very new to Redux, so any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? What doesn't work? What does `request` look like in the log?

Comment: Added an update with the reducer and console logs

Comment: For starters, I probably split the two api calls into two actions. Also I'd recommend using some kind of middleware, because as it is your logs are written before the promise gets resolved. Have a look here https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1676

Comment: You're probably looking for [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), a redux middleware that let you return a function from your reducer that will be evaluated later (when the promise resolves).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem. In this function,

```
export function fetchCurrentCity() {
  const request = axios.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
    .then(response => {
      const lat = reponse.data.latitude;
      const lon = response.data.longitude;
      const url = `${ROOT_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;

      axios.get(url);
    }) 

  console.log('Request 2:', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_CURRENT_CITY,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

You should not just return the object `{ type: FETCH_CURRENT_CITY, payload: request }`. They are supposed to be **dispatched**.

The function should have a structure like this:

```
    export function actionWeatherData(response) {
      // change 3: dispatch!
      return {
        type:...
        payload: ....
      }
    }

    export function fetchWeatherData(url) {
      ....
      const promise = axios.get(url);
      ....
      promise.then((response) => {
        // Change 2. weather data is ready, now dispatch the payload to store
        dispatch(actionWeatherData(response));
      }
    }

    export function fetchCurrentCity() {
      const request = axios.get('http://freegeoip.net/json/')
        .then(response => {
          const lat = reponse.data.latitude;
          const lon = response.data.longitude;
          const url = `${ROOT_URL}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;
          // Change 1. Fetch weather data
          fetchWeatherData(url);
          return response;
        }) 

      console.log('Request 2:', request);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, really new to redux, only did the course on Udemy. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Code looks really foreign to me. I think I need to read up more about redux :( Is this in any way related to redux thunk as someone mentioned in comments above?